# How to quick select PNG image for masking in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, mask

Is that possible to generate mask from Layer Alpha Channel?

I want to quick select this image for masking.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Maybe someone will need it.

Layer -> Auto-Trace

Comment: Worth noting that you can also use a layer as a track matte for other layers. https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/alpha-channels-masks-mattes.html#track_mattes_and_traveling_mattes